# How to store file path using PHP file upload

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, filepath

I have a file upload code. I face some problem. I want to save file path in database which is uploaded by user but I failed in it. Can you please help me.

Here is my code

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test123"; // Database name 
//$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(! $con)
{
die('Connection Failed'.mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("test123",$con);

if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
    $errors= array();
    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];
        $file_path=$_FILES['files']['path'][$key];  
        if($file_size > 2097152){
            $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }       
        $query="INSERT into upload(`FILE_NAME`,`FILE_SIZE`,`FILE_TYPE`,`FILE_PATH`) VALUES('$file_name','$file_size','$file_type', '$file_path'); ";
$desired_dir="user_data";
        //$desired_dir=$options['upload_dir']."user_data";
        if(empty($errors)==true){
            if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 755);     // Create directory if it does not exist
            }
            if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
            }else{                                  // rename the file if another one exist
                $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
                 rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
            }
         mysql_query($query);           
        }else{
                print_r($errors);
        }
    }
    if(empty($error)){
        echo "Success";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You should first upload the file and then save the name in the database.

Comment: @AnkiiGangrade How i can do it can u give me a hint by writing some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try something like this :

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password="root"; // Mysql password
$db_name="test"; // Database name
//$tbl_name="members"; // Table name
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(! $con)
{
    die('Connection Failed'.mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("test123",$con);

if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
    $errors= array();
    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];
        $file_path=$_FILES['files']['path'][$key];
        if($file_size > 2097152){
            $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }

        //$desired_dir=$options['upload_dir']."user_data";
        $desired_dir="user_data";
        if(empty($errors)==true)
        {
            if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 755);     // Create directory if it does not exist
            }

            $file_path_name = "$desired_dir/".$file_name;

            if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
            }else{                                  // rename the file if another one exist
                $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
                rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;
            }

            $query="INSERT into upload(`FILE_NAME`,`FILE_SIZE`,`FILE_TYPE`,`FILE_PATH`) VALUES('$file_name','$file_size','$file_type', '$file_path_name'); ";
            mysql_query($query);
        }else{
            print_r($errors);
        }
    }
    if(empty($error)){
        echo "Success";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: It's impossible to tell what you've changed.

Comment: If you look at the code then you will know what I have changed. @Ja͢ck

Comment: That's a sad excuse, you could just mention what you've changed in the answer instead of making others who come by dissect your code.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I'm doing this, I'll just store the exact file name (**the name given to the file after it has been moved to the desired location**) to the database. Then when I want to retrieve I just append the file name to the file path.

Like:

```
<img src = "/user_data/<?php echo ($file_name); ?>.png";
```

Reasons:

1. Storing the slashes and extensions can make the database messy. (**Personal Preference**).
2. By default the user_data folder is always going to be available so why not reference to it directly in order to make my codes more readable.